# Is it possible to easily change data table name in a Power App?

Tags: powerapps

I am developing a canvas Power App application. It works with an SQL Server table; let’s call it MyTable. While I am on development stage, I do not want to work with the real MyTable; instead I have created MyTableTemp. My app works with it.
Now let’s suppose that I have finished the application. It is tested; and it is time to switch it from MyTableTemp to MyTable.
The question is: is there a simple way to do this? I do not see an easy way; there are many places in the app that refer ‘MyTable’.  Is it possible to create a data source that initially points out to MyTable and later points out to MyTableTemp; and use this data source in the app

Answer (score 0):

One approch can be, unpack the app, replace references and then repack the app :

```
pac canvas unpack --msapp WithTempTable.msapp --sources MySource
```

replace MyTableTemp by MyTable

```
pac canvas pack --sources MySource --msapp WithFinalTable.msapp
```